# heroku create should not name remote as "heroku"

Tags: heroku

When I do

```
heroku create
```

then a remote is added with name heroku.

I want that name to be changed to "heroku1". Is it possible?

I know it might be a bad practice but we have a complicated situation.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Not bad practice at all - I very rarely even have heroku in there at all - it's just a name for how you want to refer to the remote. I typically use development or production.

To rename a remote is easy;

```
git remote rename heroku heroku1
```

Answer (score 4):

You can specify the name of the remote as part of the `heroku create` command, as well:

```
heroku create --remote heroku1
```

There are other useful options as well, `heroku help create` for details.

I don't see why it's bad practice — the name should be whatever helps you (or any other developers on the project) understand the process. For example, one of my apps has two Heroku remotes, *staging* and *heroku*. The *staging* app lets us test things out and is just on the free service level, where the *heroku* app is the live user-facing site, and is scaled up appropriately.

Comment: How do you use the CLI commands with different remotes? For instance, if you type in "heroku logs --tail", which remote do you receive logs for?

Comment: You need to add an app flag, so it would become "heroku logs --tail -a nameofherokuapp"